# Test if a string is equal to one of the strings (with regex)

Tags: php, regex

How could this be done with regex?

```
 return ( $s=='aa' || $s=='bb' || $s=='cc' || $s=='dd' ) ? 1 : 0;
```

I am trying:

```
 $s = 'aa';
 $result = preg_match( '/(aa|bb|cc|dd)/', $s );
 echo $result; // 1
```

but obviously this returns `1` if `$s` contains one or more of the specified strings (not when it is equal to one of them).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to use start `^` and end `$` anchors to do an exact string match.

```
$result = preg_match( '/^(aa|bb|cc|dd)$/', $s );
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$s = 'aa';
$result = preg_match( '/^(aa|bb|cc|dd)$/', $s );
echo $result;
```

Use ^ and $ to specify the to match from the beginning of the input till the end.

Answer (score 3):

I think RegEx overkill for this problem.

My solution:

```
$results = array('aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd');
$c = 'aa';

if(in_array($c, $results, true)) {
    echo 'YES';
} else {
    echo 'NO';
}
```

Comment: What it means "overkill" ? I'm not agree with you.

Comment: The difference is negligible, you can use whichever you prefer - https://eval.in/223092

Comment: @Styphon, your comparison not equal.

https://eval.in/private/81d6123d2cd184 - https://eval.in/private/481f2ed8552cb2

Comment: @AdilIlhan Run them on the same script, eval.in will not give accurate results if they're on different pages. Each time you run it you will get a different result of up to 0.2s.

Comment: @Styphon Your code wrong! Doesn't have $c variable. But you are using $c variable in in_array function. Also you are using if statement for in_array function but just set $result variable for preg_match.

Comment: @Leandro, I think using RegEx for simple string processing performance consuming. Please look 3th comment.

Comment: The 90% of bad performance is about bad arquitechture and/or analysis

Comment: @Leandro, Fair enough! But discussion on two function working time and performance, thanks.

Comment: Although I am not going to use this approach in this case, +1 for starting another interesting RegEx vs world micro optimisation battle.

Comment: @AdilIlhan Finally spotted what you meant. It would have just been easier for you to correct the mistake you know? Anyway, here is my eval.in corrected and showing the negligible difference between the two. https://eval.in/223483